# change the storage for the attached files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I was given a requirement where users can upload files to shared network drive not to SharePoint by clicking the attach button on SharePoint list NewItemForm.

What they need is to change the storage for the attached files, due to sensitivity

Answer (score 2):

The users can upload the attachment files to shared network drive. It just can work for the existing items in the list.

You could map shared network drive with the list in SharePoint.

Then in the windows explorer, there is a folder named with the list name such as “list1”.

In the “list1” folder, there is a folder named “Attachments”.

You could create the folder named with the ID of the existing item, and move the files to the folder named with item ID.

It will associate the file to the corresponding item as the attachment automatically. You can see the attachment file of the item in the browser when viewing the item in the list.

[image]

More reference:

Map SharePoint Libraries with local file drive – A step-by-step guide.

https://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/09/06/map-sharepoint-libraries-with-local-file-drive-a-step-by-step-guide/

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible out of the box. Below is a workaround

1. Create a custom form for displaying/adding new item to the list
2. In this form you need to provide a file link which points to the Network Drive where you want to store the attachments
3. During saving the List Item you need to save the FileURL into the List
4. During rendering if FileURL's are present then display it as Attachment Links.

Comment: Hey Amal, do you have sample that you did before ?

Comment: Sorry never came across this requirement before..